# EOF when reading a line in competitive website, namely Code Chef

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

I'm trying to solve a problem using the following code:

```
X,Y = map(float, input().split())

if X < Y and not X % 5:
    print(Y - X - 0.50)
else:
    print(Y)
```

This code gives me the desired output when I run using IDLE. However, when I try running this code using an interpreter provided by a competitive programming website, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I tried reading the answers of other similar questions, but none of them seemed to work in my case.

Comment: Maybe the interpreter isn't passing any information to stdin, so your `input` call fails to get anything. Are you sure you're supposed to be getting X and Y through input? Maybe they're actually command line arguments or something. What competitive programming website is this, specifically?

Comment: Without having actual samples of the problem, it's hard to say.  Try debugging this by decoupling your input process: grab a line of input, check its contents for validity, print the line, etc.  See what sort of input is crashing your program.  It may be as simple as recognizing a null line at the end of the file.

Comment: What is the function call `input()` ? is that supposed to be the standard python 3.x [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input)? maybe need to pull that line out out, and first `user_input = input().split()` and get the result first, then pass that user input into `map(float, user_input)`

Comment: @Kevin It's CodeChef

Comment: @Prune The values do get recognised and work in IDLE

Comment: @downshift Yes, It's the standard input() in 3.x. I tried your suggestion i.e. input().split() too, doesn't work.

Comment: @user3632345: I understand that it works in IDLE.  I'm wondering what output you get when you run on CodeChef.  Do you not get to see the full output?

Comment: @Prune I get the error. No output. That's the problem. (Also, trying the problem in c++ works out fine)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the reason but the program is trying to read after the end of the data. You can solve the problem by exception handling

```
try:
    data = input()
except EOFError:
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

The competitive programming website is likely running python 2. Python 2 treats `input()` differently than python 3.

You should rather use `raw_input()` than `input()`.

From the docs:

> [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Your problem can be explained from what was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x):

> In Python 2, raw_input() returns a string, and input() tries to run
>   the input as a Python expression.

Comment: You can choose which language to run it in. So, no that's not the problem. I'm explicitly running it in python 3.4

Comment: Are you providing the input using the "custom input" feature on codechef?
I did not run into any problem providing: `1 2`

Comment: custom works fine. Just not their input. For reference use problem code HS08TEST in the compiler

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly where you are running the code and what input you are providing.

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at the codechef page. Notice the checkbox marked 'Custom Input'. With that checked/ticked a textbox will open where you can put your input lines.

[image: codechef image]